# CTE query doesn't print the right structure?

Tags: sql-server, cte

I have this table which represents hierarchy :

```
childID  parentID          NAME          siblingOrder
1          1               a               0
212        1               ab              1
112        1               ac              2
412        1               ad              3
-912       112             aca             0
```

The structure is:

```
a
+----ab
+----ac
     +---aca
+----ad
```

(The `siblingOrder`column is for controlling the order of `ab`,`ac`,`ad`  )

I already have this solution which uses the  `siblingOrder` :

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT childID, parentID, 0 AS depth, NAME , siblingOrder,
         CAST(RIGHT('00000' + CAST(siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)  AS VARCHAR(1024))  AS PATH
   FROM   @myTable
   WHERE   childID = parentID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  TBL.childID, TBL.parentID,
           CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name ,TBL.siblingOrder,
           CAST(cte.Path + '.' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Tbl.siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)AS VARCHAR(1024) )
    FROM   @myTable AS TBL
            INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
    WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
SELECT path,depth, childID, parentID, siblingOrder, REPLICATE('----', depth) + name
FROM CTE
  ORDER BY PATH
```

So `order by` `PATH` actually do the job  :

[image]

**The problem:**

The problem is that I *Must(!)* put values in the `siblingOrder` in order for it to work !

Otherwise  , For example :

If I put `0` in all `siblingOrder` this is the result :

[image]

(yes,  now sorting by path  - doesn't work...)

**I need  that `aca` will always be under `ac`**

*(The only reason I added the `siblingOrder` is to order siblings !) and I don't want to enforce adding `siblingOrder` when not needed*

**Question :**

Is it possible to enhance the query so that `siblingOrder` will affect only to siblings ?

I mean , If I don't care about the order of the siblings ( by putting `0`) , I still expect the `aca` to be under `ac`

[**Sqlonline : with siblingOrder**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/127361)

[**Sqlonline - without siblingOrder**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/127363)

Comment: Why are you posting the same question to multiple sites? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064928/cte-query-doesnt-print-the-right-structure

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm about to delete it in SO. ( I think it is better to ask here)

Comment: Probably better for your account, in general, if you vote to migrate it than delete it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks a lot. didn't know that. anyway I hope that this issue of mine (which i'm struggling with for days) - will finally be solved here....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the `parentID` and the `childID`in the path. So instead of

```
RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Tbl.siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
```

you should write

```
RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(Tbl.parentID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Tbl.siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(Tbl.childID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)
```

(That is in two places in your code)

Used this way you can provide the siblingOrder where desired. If present it will override the child order. If not present the children will be ordered by their childID.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9cee/1) without siblingOrder

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
    ([childID] int, [parentID] int, [NAME] varchar(3), [siblingOrder] int)
;

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
    ([childID], [parentID], [NAME], [siblingOrder])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'a', 0),
    (212, 1, 'ab', 0),
    (112, 1, 'ac', 0),
    (412, 1, 'ad', 0),
    (-912, 112, 'aca', 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT childID, parentID, 0 AS depth, NAME , siblingOrder,
         CAST(RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(parentID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)+ RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(childID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)  AS VARCHAR(1024))  AS PATH
   FROM   dbo.MyTable 
   WHERE   childID = parentID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  TBL.childID, TBL.parentID,
           CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name ,TBL.siblingOrder,
           CAST(cte.Path + '.' + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(Tbl.parentID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Tbl.siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)+ RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(Tbl.childID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) AS VARCHAR(1024) )
    FROM   dbo.MyTable AS TBL
            INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
    WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
SELECT path,depth, childID, parentID, siblingOrder, REPLICATE('----', depth) + name
FROM CTE
  ORDER BY PATH
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9cee/1/0)**:

```
|                                                                             PATH | DEPTH | CHILDID | PARENTID | SIBLINGORDER |    COLUMN_5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       00000000010000000000000001 |     0 |       1 |        1 |            0 |           a |
|                            00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000000000000112 |     1 |     112 |        1 |            0 |      ----ac |
| 00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000000000000112.0000000112000000000000-912 |     2 |    -912 |      112 |            0 | --------aca |
|                            00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000000000000212 |     1 |     212 |        1 |            0 |      ----ab |
|                            00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000000000000412 |     1 |     412 |        1 |            0 |      ----ad |
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9cee/1) with siblingOrder

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
    ([childID] int, [parentID] int, [NAME] varchar(3), [siblingOrder] int)
;

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
    ([childID], [parentID], [NAME], [siblingOrder])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'a', 0),
    (212, 1, 'ab', 1),
    (112, 1, 'ac', 3),
    (412, 1, 'ad', 2),
    (-912, 112, 'aca', 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT childID, parentID, 0 AS depth, NAME , siblingOrder,
         CAST(RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(parentID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)+ RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(childID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)  AS VARCHAR(1024))  AS PATH
   FROM   dbo.MyTable 
   WHERE   childID = parentID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  TBL.childID, TBL.parentID,
           CTE.depth + 1 , TBL.name ,TBL.siblingOrder,
           CAST(cte.Path + '.' + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(Tbl.parentID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Tbl.siblingOrder AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)+ RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(Tbl.childID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) AS VARCHAR(1024) )
    FROM   dbo.MyTable AS TBL
            INNER JOIN CTE  ON  TBL.parentID = CTE.childID
    WHERE   TBL.childID<>TBL.parentID
)
SELECT path,depth, childID, parentID, siblingOrder, REPLICATE('----', depth) + name
FROM CTE
  ORDER BY PATH
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9cee/1/0)**:

```
|                                                                             PATH | DEPTH | CHILDID | PARENTID | SIBLINGORDER |    COLUMN_5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       00000000010000000000000001 |     0 |       1 |        1 |            0 |           a |
|                            00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000010000000212 |     1 |     212 |        1 |            1 |      ----ab |
|                            00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000020000000412 |     1 |     412 |        1 |            2 |      ----ad |
|                            00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000030000000112 |     1 |     112 |        1 |            3 |      ----ac |
| 00000000010000000000000001.00000000010000030000000112.0000000112000000000000-912 |     2 |    -912 |      112 |            0 | --------aca |
```