# Hierarchy of Employee "names" with CTE: Cannot create a correct version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cte

I am trying to create the correct structure of my sql (CTE) query, but I can not. This is a version I want to have [image: correct version].

And this is my current version: [image: what i have now]. As you can see there are duplicates and i have no idea how to get rid of them. Futhermore the structure is wrong. I already tried to look for solutions like here but was unable to come up with solution.
[CTE query doesn't print the right structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47585/cte-query-doesnt-print-the-right-structure)

My Employee table looks like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/428d2/2

Here is my SQL query I use to create the correct name column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf4c1/4

I use MsSQL 2012, so feel free to use newest fuctions etc. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you specify the root node in the CTE, it works ok. Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf4c1/9

Comment: Hi @Phil. I thank you very much. Didn't know that at all. Thanks again. Please post your answer in "as an answer" and not a comment and will give "+".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the root node in the CTE, it works ok.

```
WITH Empl_Tab( Id ,
                 ParentId ,
                 LEVEL,
             [Order]
) AS ( SELECT Employee.[EMPl Id] ,  Employee.[reports to the Boss] ,
                0 AS LEVEL ,
              CONVERT([varchar](MAX), Employee.[EMPl Id]) AS [Order]
           FROM Employee
where [reports to the Boss] = 1
        UNION ALL

        SELECT Employee.[EMPl Id] ,
                Employee.[reports to the Boss] ,
                Empl_Tab.LEVEL+1 AS LEVEL ,
             Empl_Tab.[Order] + CONVERT([varchar](30), Employee.[EMPl Id]) AS [Order]
           FROM
                Employee INNER JOIN Empl_Tab
                ON Empl_Tab.Id = Employee.[reports to the Boss] 
     )

SELECT REPLICATE( '.' ,Empl_Tab.Id*1 )+Employee.Name AS Name
  FROM
       Employee INNER JOIN Empl_Tab
       ON Empl_Tab.Id = Employee.[EMPl Id]
  ORDER BY Empl_Tab.[Order]
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf4c1/9).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf4c1/4), you are on the right track with only a **key point** missing.

The [syntax (from BOL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of a recursive CTE is :

```
WITH cte_name ( column_name [,...n] )
AS
(
CTE_query_definition –- Anchor member is defined.
UNION ALL
CTE_query_definition –- Recursive member is defined referencing cte_name.
)
-- Statement using the CTE
SELECT *
FROM cte_name
```

You are missing creating the base result set - which is the highest level in the hierarchy. This is identified by `[reports to the Boss] = 1`. So if you might have a CEO that does not report to anyone, he will have it set to NULL.

```
SELECT Employee.[EMPl Id] ,  Employee.[reports to the Boss] ,
                0 AS LEVEL ,
              CONVERT([varchar](MAX), Employee.[EMPl Id]) AS [Order]
           FROM Employee
where [reports to the Boss] = 1
```

The rest of the query in your fiddle looks fine.

To get you the results that you have shown, below will work:

```
;WITH Empl_Tab( Id ,
                 ParentId ,
                 LEVEL,
             [Order]
) AS ( SELECT Employee.[EMPl Id] ,  Employee.[reports to the Boss] ,
                0 AS LEVEL ,
              CONVERT([varchar](MAX), Employee.[EMPl Id]) AS [Order]
           FROM Employee
where [reports to the Boss] = 1
        UNION ALL

        SELECT Employee.[EMPl Id] ,
                Employee.[reports to the Boss] ,
                Empl_Tab.LEVEL+1 AS LEVEL ,
             Empl_Tab.[Order] + CONVERT([varchar](30), Employee.[EMPl Id]) AS [Order]
           FROM
                Employee INNER JOIN Empl_Tab
                ON Empl_Tab.Id = Employee.[reports to the Boss] 
     )

SELECT REPLICATE( ' ' ,Empl_Tab.Id*1 )+Employee.Name AS NAME,
        Id as EMPID,
        ParentId as SUPERVISORFK,
        POSITION
  FROM
       Employee INNER JOIN Empl_Tab
       ON Empl_Tab.Id = Employee.[EMPl Id]
  ORDER BY Empl_Tab.[Order]
```

[image]

Hope that helps to understand.

Also, look at the query that @Phil has on fiddle.

Comment: @johnmalc NP .. As long as we help each other, its fine. I just made sure that you understood the way CTE works as you were almost close, but missing the **key** point.

Comment: Up vote for you Kin :)